# How can I use break or continue within for loop in Twig template?

Tags: php, symfony, for-loop, twig, break

I try to use a simple loop, in my real code this loop is more complex, and I need to `break` this iteration like:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.id == 10 %}
        {# break #}
    {% endif %}
    <h2>{{ post.heading }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I use behavior of `break` or `continue` of PHP control structures in Twig?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

This can be **nearly** done by setting a new variable as a flag to `break` iterating:

```
{% set break = false %}
{% for post in posts if not break %}
    <h2>{{ post.heading }}</h2>
    {% if post.id == 10 %}
        {% set break = true %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

An uglier, but working example for `continue`:

```
{% set continue = false %}
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.id == 10 %}
        {% set continue = true %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if not continue %}
        <h2>{{ post.heading }}</h2>
    {% endif %}
    {% if continue %}
        {% set continue = false %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

> But there is **no** performance profit, only similar behaviour to the built-in `break` and `continue` statements like in flat PHP.

Comment: It is useful. In my case I just need to show / get the first result. Is there a way in Twig to get just the first value? This is only for better performance purposes.

Comment: @pathros In order to get the first value, use the `first` twig filter: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/first.html

Comment: Love the note. Been trying my last 10mins finding something that not's really helpful :D

Comment: It's worth noting that this will **not** break the code execution, anything below `set break = true` will be executed unless you put it in an `else` statement. See https://twigfiddle.com/euio5w

Comment: @Gus Yep, that's why I was meaning to put that if statement with `set break = true` in the very _end_. But yeah, it depends on your code, so thanks for mentioning it to clarify

Comment: But wouldn't it be easier to do this: (I don't know how to format it on this page)

`{% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.id != 10 %}
           <h2>{{ post.heading }}</h2>
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}`

Comment: I use twig 3.x and had an issue with this method `if not break`
I've got this error `Uncaught Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unexpected token "name" of value "if"`

Comment: `Symfony: Twig conditional 'for' syntax is deprecated as of Twig 2.10`

Answer (score 148):

From docs TWIG 2.x [docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition):

> Unlike in PHP, it's not possible to break or continue in a loop.

But still:

> You can however filter the sequence during iteration which allows you to skip items.

Example 1 (for huge lists you can filter posts using [slice](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/slice.html), `slice(start, length)`):

```
{% for post in posts|slice(0,10) %}
    <h2>{{ post.heading }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Example 2 works TWIG 3.0 as well:

```
{% for post in posts if post.id < 10 %}
    <h2>{{ post.heading }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

You can even use own [TWIG filters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html#create-the-extension-class) for more complexed conditions, like:

```
{% for post in posts|onlySuperPosts %}
    <h2>{{ post.heading }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Moreover if you wanna achive break loop after 10 iteration you could use sth like that: `{% for post in posts|slice(0,10) %}`

Comment: OK, thanks, I probably missed `Unlike in PHP, it's not possible to break or continue in a loop.` when read the docs. But I think `break` and `continue` is a good features, which would need to add

Comment: You can't access loop variable in the loop statement!

Comment: doesn't work. long list, `for` should be breakable after first hit.
@VictorBocharsky 's answer is right

Comment: @VasiliiSuricov you can use `{% for post in posts|slice(0,10) %}` for huge lists. See my first comment. I've also updated my answer.

Comment: @NHG do you sure that needed element (because i need just one) will be in this slice? how you decided? 
i'll give you an example: list contains 999 elements, needed is on position 12.
so first example wrong, 2nd and 3rd will check all 999 elements

Comment: @NHG, oh, sorry, i'm damn, `for` will run 999 times **anyway**

Comment: @VasiliiSuricov what's wrong with using arguments for `slice(start, length)`? In your example with 999 records: `slice(12, 1)`

Comment: @NHG wrng is that i dont know which one is right, i have to check. order in array can be different.
>> you can use {% for post in posts|slice(0,10) %} 
not, u can't

Comment: @VasiliiSuricov please ask separated question for your specific case (I'll try to help) to avoid off-top discussion in comments section.

Comment: A heads up, while it's available in 2.0, Twig removed the {% for ... if ... %} statement in version 3.0.

Comment: Twig conditional 'for' syntax is deprecated as of Twig 2.10.

Comment: The replacement for the for... if... statement, could be used the filter "filter", something like this:
{% for banner in banners|filter(b => b.isVisible) %}
This works in twig 3.5

Answer (score 16):

A way to be able to use `{% break %}` or `{% continue %}` is to write `TokenParser`s for them.

I did it for the `{% break %}` token in the code below. You can, without much modifications, do the same thing for the `{% continue %}`.

- **AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension.php**:

  ```
  namespace AppBundle\Twig;

  class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
  {
      function getTokenParsers() {
          return array(
              new BreakToken(),
          );
      }

      public function getName()
      {
          return 'app_extension';
      }
  }
  ```
- **AppBundle\Twig\BreakToken.php**:

  ```
  namespace AppBundle\Twig;

  class BreakToken extends \Twig_TokenParser
  {
      public function parse(\Twig_Token $token)
      {
          $stream = $this->parser->getStream();
          $stream->expect(\Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE);

          // Trick to check if we are currently in a loop.
          $currentForLoop = 0;

          for ($i = 1; true; $i++) {
              try {
                  // if we look before the beginning of the stream
                  // the stream will throw a \Twig_Error_Syntax
                  $token = $stream->look(-$i);
              } catch (\Twig_Error_Syntax $e) {
                  break;
              }

              if ($token->test(\Twig_Token::NAME_TYPE, 'for')) {
                  $currentForLoop++;
              } else if ($token->test(\Twig_Token::NAME_TYPE, 'endfor')) {
                  $currentForLoop--;
              }
          }


          if ($currentForLoop < 1) {
              throw new \Twig_Error_Syntax(
                  'Break tag is only allowed in \'for\' loops.',
                  $stream->getCurrent()->getLine(),
                  $stream->getSourceContext()->getName()
              );
          }

          return new BreakNode();
      }

      public function getTag()
      {
          return 'break';
      }
  }
  ```
- **AppBundle\Twig\BreakNode.php**:

  ```
  namespace AppBundle\Twig;

  class BreakNode extends \Twig_Node
  {
      public function compile(\Twig_Compiler $compiler)
      {
          $compiler
              ->write("break;\n")
          ;
      }
  }
  ```

Then you can simply use `{% break %}` to get out of loops like this:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.id == 10 %}
        {% break %}
    {% endif %}
    <h2>{{ post.heading }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

---

To go even further, you may write token parsers for `{% continue X %}` and `{% break X %}` (where X is an integer >= 1) to [get out/continue multiple loops like in PHP](http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.break.php).

Comment: That's just overkill. Twig loops should be supporting breaks and continues natively.

Comment: This is nice if you don't want to/can't use filters.

Comment: The [`squirrelphp/twig-php-syntax` library](https://github.com/squirrelphp/twig-php-syntax) provides `{% break %}`, `{% break n %}` and `{% continue %}` tokens.

Comment: @mtsknn and the authors used and improved the code that I wrote for this answer!

Comment: @JulesLamur, you said "@mtsknn and the authors," but I'm not involved with that library.

Comment: @mtsknn sorry that's a technical misunderstanding, I meant it to be read like that: "The X library provides `{% break %}`, `{% break n %}` and `{% continue %}` tokens and the authors used and improved the code [...]". Your name in the comment was only here because I replied to you.

Comment: @JulesLamur, right, no worries. Now that I took a look at the library code ([`BreakOrContinueTokenParser.php`](https://github.com/squirrelphp/twig-php-syntax/blob/v1.5.1/src/TokenParser/BreakOrContinueTokenParser.php)), it's clearly based on your code.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but that's a brilliant answer, and the mentioned library from squirrelphp/twig-php-syntax is an awesome feat! Thank you JulesLamur and @MatiasKinnunen for your information

Answer (score 8):

From @NHG comment — works perfectly

```
{% for post in posts|slice(0,10) %}
```

Comment: @Basit if posts are ordered by date?

Comment: −1. Will not work in a lot of cases. For instance, in the OP’s code, what if posts aren’t ordered by id, or if there is no post for some ids?

Answer (score 6):

I have found a good work-around for continue (love the break sample above).
Here I do not want to list "agency". In PHP I'd "continue" but in twig, I came up with alternative:

```
{% for basename, perms in permsByBasenames %} 
    {% if basename == 'agency' %}
        {# do nothing #}
    {% else %}
        <a class="scrollLink" onclick='scrollToSpot("#{{ basename }}")'>{{ basename }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

OR I simply skip it if it doesn't meet my criteria:

```
{% for tr in time_reports %}
    {% if not tr.isApproved %}
        .....
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```