# Search Filter - Angular Js inside Twig loop

Tags: angularjs, symfony, twig

I am playing around Angular JS as it seems that its learning curve is steep for a junior developer like me.I created angular file and use this $interpolateProvider provider in order to work with twig markup/syntax.

```
var customApp = angular.module('customApp', []);

  customApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
 });

  customApp.controller('customController', function($scope) {
   $scope.message = 'Ok symfony2';
 });
```

Now in view, that's easy

```
 <div ng-app="customApp" ng-controller="customController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="message" />
      // message //
 </div>
```

Now I want this to use in search mechanism like so

```
 <div ng-app="customApp" ng-controller="customController">
    Search <input type="text" placeholder="search your name" ng-model="searchText" /><br />
 </div>
```

Using Angular ng-repeat directive, I can use it in loop something like

```
 <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter:searchText>
   <td>//employee.name//</td>
   <td>//employee.lastname//</td>
 </tr>
```

Now my problem is, the data is dynamically 'fetch' from database and I displaying it using Twig's for loop

```
{% for employee in employees %}
  <tr {% if loop.index is odd %}class="color"{% endif %}>
     <td>{{ employee.name }}</td>
     <td>{{ employee.lastname }}</td> 
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

How to use the Angular search Filter here?

```
 {% for employee in employees | filter:searchText %}
 ......
```

Twig is complaining here...

**update**

As i dig deeper into Symfony docs, I understand that inorder for the Angular JS fetch the data from database, I have to create a service or controller which then called by angular

emp.yml

```
emp_angular:
path: /emps-angular
defaults: { _controller: "Bundle:Emp:emp_angular" }
```

Controller

```
public function emp_angularAction(Request $request)
{
    $names= array();
    //$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    //$datas = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Voters')->getAllVotersDesc();

    $datas = array('manila','quezon','pasig','makatis');temp data for testing
   // dump($data);

   foreach ($datas as $data)
    {
        $names[] = $data;
    }

    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData($names);
     return $response;
   // return $this->render('Bundle:Emp:data.html.twig', array(
      //  'names' => $response,
    //));
}
```

with this, I can pull the data successfully

```
["manila","quezon","pasig","makatis"]
```

However I really confused on how Angular fetch the url

```
customApp.controller('customController', function($scope,$http) {
$scope.message = 'Ok symfony2';
$http({method:'GET',url:'{{ path('emp_angular')}}'}).success( function(response){
    $scope.names = response;
});
```

});

This file doen't return anything

In plain php, The url inside $http is called like this

```
$http({method:'GET', url:'page2.php'}).success(function(response){
$scope.names = response;
```

Where page2.php is the file that retrieves data from database

How to use this in Angular?

**Update**

Almost did it, only 1 remaining problem..

I refactor my codes here

The view

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body -%}

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
 //names //
<table ng-model="names">
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>//x.id//</td>
    <td>//x.name//</td>
  </tr>
</table>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
 {{ parent() }}
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
    });

    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        //$http.get("http://localhost:8093/voters/voters_angular")
        $http.get("{{ path('emp_angular') }}")
        .success(function (data,status, headers, config) {$scope.names = data;});
    });
    //console.log(names);
 </script>  
 {% endblock %}
```

The route file for this

```
 emp_angular:
  path: /voters-angular
  defaults: { _controller: "Bundle:Voters:voters_angular" }

 angular:
  path: /angular
  defaults: { _controller: "Bundle:Voters:angular" }
```

Refactored controller

```
  public function voters_angularAction(Request $request)
{
    $names = array();


    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('Bundle:City')->createQueryBuilder('c')
       ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC')
       ->getQuery()
       ->getResult();

    foreach ($entities as $entity)
    {
        $names[] = $entity->getName();
    }

    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData($names);

    return $response;
}

public function angularAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('Bundle:Voters:data.html.twig');
}
```

in twig

```
 // names //
```

successfully displaying data

```
 ["Aborlan ","Abra de Ilog ","Abucay ","Abulug ","Abuyog ","Adams"]
```

how to convert this to string?

But ng-repeat directive doesnt work here

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
<td>//x.id//</td>
<td>//x.name//</td>
</tr>
```

What's the possible fix for this?Is there's something wrong with the symfony controller itself?

Comment: Are you expecting tons of data to be displayed in production?

Comment: Definitely.Hundreds of thousands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code almost working.The reason for the ng-repeat directive not working is

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>//x.name//</td> 
</tr>
```

because in your symfony controller, you already loop your result, so instead use

```
 <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
     <td>//x//</td> 
 </tr>
```

Lets refactor your angular controller

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
    });

    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        //$http.get("http://localhost:8093/voters/voters_angular")
        $http.get("{{ path('emp_angular') }}")
        .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response;});
    });
    //console.log(names);
</script>
```

And now your view

```
{% block body -%}

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

 <table ng-model="names" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Full Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names track by $index">
        <td>//x//</td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody> 
 </table>
</div>  
{% endblock %}
```

You may wonder why in your ng-repeat directive I change your code to

```
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names track by $index">
        <td>//x//</td> 
  </tr>
```

Well you mentioned earlier that you are expecting tons of data, and it maybe possible for duplicates, so so prevent that error,

```
 track by $index
```

is added as described here

[link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes)

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing server-side variables with front-end. Usually AngularJs uses API from server to fetch data by ajax and passes it in templates.

In your case you can create variable in template by ng-init directive but you should encode it in json first:

There is example for you:

```
{% set employees = [{'name':'One'},{'name':'Two'}] %}

<div ng-app="EmployeeApp">
    <div ng-controller="EmployeeListCtrl" ng-init='employees={{ employees|json_encode|raw }}'>
        <ul ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter: searchText">
            <li>//employee.name//</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Zhuravlev Do you have any Idea how to fetch data from the controller and pass it to angular to display in view?

Comment: You are passing variable to twig template, not to angular. You should understand the difference between server side framework(symfony2) and front-end(angularjs). All info is here http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html

Comment: I almost got the solution.I will update later.My problem now is trimmed down on passing the json response in twig