# How to "break" a loop in Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to use `break` in the Twig template engine.

```
{% for key, db_staff_language in db_staff_languages %}
  {% for staff_language in model_data.staff_languages %}
    {% if staff_language.id == db_staff_language.id %}
        <option value="{{db_staff_language.id}}" selected="selected">{{db_staff_language.staff_languages_data_translation[0].value}}</option>
    {% else %}
        <option value="{{db_staff_language.id}}">{{db_staff_language.staff_languages_data_translation[0].value}}</option>
    {% endif %}
    {% break %}   {# <-- Not working #}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

As I couldn't solve the problem with Twig, I also tried other things, like:

```
-----------------------------------------------
{% autoescape true %}
<?php echo 'test' ?>
{% endautoescape %}
-----------------------------------------------
{% php %}
<?php echo 'test' ?>
{% endphp %}
-----------------------------------------------
{% verbatim %}
<?php echo "test"; ?>
{% endverbatim %}
-----------------------------------------------
{{ raw }}
<?php echo "test"; ?>
{{ endraw }}
-----------------------------------------------
```

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Quoting [the documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition): "Unlike in PHP, it's not possible to break or continue in a loop. You can however filter the sequence during iteration which allows you to skip items."

Comment: Unlike in PHP, it's not possible to break or continue in a loop. Check if you can adding-a-condition as described [here in the doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use break or continue within for in twig template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672796/how-can-i-use-break-or-continue-within-for-in-twig-template)

Answer (score 4):

Twig doesn't include a break statement. According to the official manual, the equivalent instruction is the [for + if condition](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition).