# foreach ( $response as $key => $element ) in Twig

Tags: loops, twig

I have the following passed as an array to my Twig template:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://somedomain.com/somepage1
            [0] => http://somedomain.com/somepage1
            [count] => 27
            [1] => 27
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://somedomain.com/somepage2
            [0] => http://somedomain.com/somepage2
            [count] => 7
            [1] => 7
        )

)
```

Now I need to do something like this:

```
foreach ( $response as $key => $element ) {
    if ( global.request.uri == $response->url ) {
        break;
    }
}
```

I know how to imitate `break` in Twig (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29161205/2418445)), but I don't know how to imitate `as $key => $element`. So how do I stop my loop when it finds an object containing the string that meets my condition? Moreover, how do I then output the value of `count` in that object?

Unlike [this question](http://my%20arrays%20contain%20multiple%20keys%20each%20with%20some%20values%20assigned%20to%20each%20key,%20and%20not%20just%20%22alpha/bravo%22%20strings), my arrays contain multiple keys each with some values assigned to each key, and not just "alpha/bravo" strings. So I don't understand how to apply the answer to that question to my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twig for loop and array with key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299202/twig-for-loop-and-array-with-key)

Comment: I found that question before posting mine, I didn't understand how to use the answer in my case though.

Comment: As you can see, my arrays contain multiple keys each with some values assigned to each key, and not just "alpha/bravo" strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your data and the comments, I'm not even sure you'd need the key to solve your problem

```
{% for item in items if item.url == uri %}
    {{ item.count }}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/oqornm)

---

**EDIT**

As of twig 2.10.0 it's deprecated to use an `if` directly inside the `for`-statement, now you either place the `if` inside the block or use the filter `filter`

```html
{% for item in items %}
    {% if item.url == uri %}
        {{ item.count }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

```html
{% for item in items|filter(v => v.url == uri) %}
    {{ item.count }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You're right... I wasn't expecting it to be as simple as this.