# Twig 3: Break in a loop

Tags: twig

Does anyone know how to loop through an array and find the first of an item then break the loop in twig?

Like this

```
Loop->find 3
- 2
- 2
- 3 - then break loop here
- 1
- 3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use break or continue within for loop in Twig template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672796/how-can-i-use-break-or-continue-within-for-loop-in-twig-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. It's working on the twig <= 2 version.

```
    {% set break = false %}
    {% set numbers = [2,2,3,1,3] %}
    {% for number in numbers if not break %}
       - {{ number }} <br/>
        {% if number == 3 %}
            {% set break = true %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

But in Twig 3, it's not working. You can try the below code it's working for twig 3.

```
        {% set break = false %}
        {% set numbers = [2,2,3,1,3] %}
        {% for number in numbers %}
            {% if break == false %}
                - {{ number }} <br/>
                {% if number == 3 %}
                    {% set break = true %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

I have read the twig 3 document but I can't fine break/continue concept on that.

**=> Output**

```
- 2
- 2
- 3
```

Comment: I have tried in the twig template and it's working.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I can't find break/continue concept on twig 3 document but I update my login for that. I think it's helpful to you.

Comment: There isn't any break/continue in twig, but the 2nd solution is the way to go